# Apply macro on cell value change : 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to apply a macro when value from a cell change. I've this code in the Dashboard Sheet :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("FilterChoice")) Is Nothing Then Call ApplyDashboardFilter
End Sub
```

The trigger works fine and the macro is executed right after, but don't know why I got an error on the Advanced filter function : "application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Option Explicit

Sub ApplyDashboardFilter()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim filterName As String
    Dim tableName As String
    filterName = "Filter" & Replace(Sheets("Dashboard").Range("FilterChoice").Value, " ", "")
    tableName = filterName + "[#All]"
    Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
    Sheets("Dashboard").Columns("A:AN").Cells.Clear
    Sheets("Critical Flows").Range("ClosingFlows[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy _
        , CriteriaRange:=Sheets(filterName).Range(tableName) _
        , CopyToRange:=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1"), Unique:=False
    Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Flows" & filterName
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Flows" & filterName).TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium3"
    If Sheets("Dashboard").Range("FilterChoice").Value = "Orchestrated" Then
        Call ApplyFlormulaRunbookName
    End If
End Sub
```

The macro works when triggered by a button on Dashboard sheet.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance,

***EDIT :***

Well, something weird happened. I just re-opened the file after a break and  **it worked**.
I suspect something happened with the ActiveSheet and / or a conflict with another workbook since I'm playing with 2 other workbooks and 10 sheets overall.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Sounds like this is an example of why you should reference the correct sheets rather than the ActiveSheet.  It looks like 'Dashboard' is the active sheet - so pass that to a variable and use that.  E.g. - `Set wrkSht = Thisworkbook.worksheets("Dashboard"): wrksht.Columns("A:AN").ClearContents: Set rng = wrksht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion` etc.....

Comment: I think that may have been the issue. Since I can't test it I assume that this is the way to go. I'm modifying my code based on your answer, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added as an answer as the comments won't allow me to format correctly.  This code just references the sheets, rather than selecting them:

```
Sub ApplyDashboardFilter()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim filterName As String
    Dim tableName As String
    Dim wrkShtDash As Worksheet
    Dim wrkShtFlows As Worksheet

    Set wrkShtDash = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Set wrkShtFlows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Critical Flows")

    filterName = "Filter" & Replace(wrkShtDash.Range("FilterChoice").Value, " ", "")
    tableName = filterName + "[#All]"
    wrkShtDash.Columns("A:AN").Cells.Clear
    wrkShtFlows.Range("ClosingFlows[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy _
        , CriteriaRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(filterName).Range(tableName) _
        , CopyToRange:=wrkShtDash.Range("A1"), Unique:=False
    Set rng = wrkShtDash.Range(wrkShtDash.Range("A1"), wrkShtDash.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
    wrkShtDash.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Flows" & filterName
    wrkShtDash.ListObjects("Flows" & filterName).TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium3"
    If wrkShtDash.Range("FilterChoice").Value = "Orchestrated" Then
        Call ApplyFlormulaRunbookName 'Spelt correctly?
    End If
End Sub
```

Note:  I haven't tested the code, it's just showing that you don't have to activate the sheet before working on it and is explicit about which file or sheet it's working with - ThisWorkbook means the file that the VBA code is in.